# Java application server connection pooling for different databases on same server

Tags: java, postgresql, glassfish, connection-pooling

I have several java application servers (glassfish 3.0) running different applications with each application requiring an unique postgresql database and thus a different connection pool for each database. My goal is to provide a master/slave db server using a passive slave for redundancy. The problem is that postgresql has a very small sweet spot for the number of active connections on the one hand and an overall reasonable limit of around 1000 active connections at all on the other. As each application is accessed by a greater number of users in peak times, each connection pool itself has to contain 50-100 connection to keep the application from locking up due to heavy parallel db io. The overall load for the database server is relatively small, it just has to provide enough connections at the moment. It just feels wrong to have so many connections open with most of them being idle most of the time.

The question is, what would be the best approach to supply (pooled) database access for all the applications while providing fallback redundancy for the database and enough parallel connection for each application to cope with peak loads?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like not a good practice, as you are better off scaling your original server than using two DBs. Keeping two DBs in sync is just too much of a hassle for practical uses, in my opinion.

To pool DB connections, you can use implementations such as Apache Commons DBCP which is very efficient on production.
However, I've never attempted to use two of such pools in conjunction.

On the other hand, you can implement connection pooling yourself, where you'll have one Great pool for the DBs, and sub-pools for each DB's connection. For this, you can re-use existing pooling implementations such as Apache Commons Pools.